# preg match not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

In learning about `preg_match()` for a project I'm working on, I've been using regexr.com to test my expressions out.  However, I've gotten an expression to work on regexr.com that isn't working once I implement it into the preg_match function.

Here's my expression that I'm working on.  What you see highlighted in blue is EXACTLY what I want.
http://regexr.com/3ccne

Here's my PHP:

```
$text = "A new quote has been logged in your online quoting system at 3\/16\/2014 10:48:13 PM.\r\n\r\nThe quote is from Cade Carrier; (email: cadecarrier@rocketmail.com) and is for these items:\r\n\r\n\r\nTires: 195 60 15 - Direct Input (2)\r\n\r\nAdditional request information:\r\n\r\nAddress:\r\n412 2nd st \r\nElton, United States Louisiana, 70532\r\nPhone: 2817399840\r\n\r\nLocation Information:\r\n\r\nYou have requested a quote from the following location:\r\nStore 16\r\n810 3rd. Ave\r\nKinder, LA 70648\r\n\r\nComments:\r\n\r\n";

preg_match('/Address:.*(, \d{5})/', $text, $address);
```

The `$address` array is empty.  What gives?

Comment: Add the `/s` modifier: [`'/Address:.*(, \d{5})/s'`](http://ideone.com/JN6oAq) - is it enough to fix the issue? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word `Address` and the comma followed by a space and 5 digits are separated with newline symbols. To force the dot to match a newline, use `/s` modifier (and I think lazy dot matching pattern is better here since it is faster to get from `Address` to the comma with five digits than backtrack from the end of the string):

```
'/Address:.*?(, \d{5})/s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iB4dO3/1) and the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/JN6oAq).

Result:

```
[0] => Address:
412 2nd st 
Elton, United States Louisiana, 70532
[1] => , 70532
```

If you do not need Item[1], just make the capturing group non-capturing: `'/Address:.*?(?:, \d{5})/s'`.

Comment: Thank you!  that `/s` modifier is not something I had heard of before!

Comment: It is called a DOTALL or singleline modifier that makes the `.` match newline symbols. Not to be confused with `/m`: multiline flag that forces `^` and `$` match start and end of a *line* in the input string (respectively).

Comment: I apologize I didn't say before, I wanted to Exclude the `Address:` from the result.  I tried `'/Address:.*([^:], \d{5})/s'` with no luck there. Thanks again.

Comment: Just move the capturing group boundaries: `'/Address:(.*?, \d{5})/s'` and grab the `$address[1]` value.